# How does Cakephp 2.x security.salt works?

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, sha1, salt

I'm trying to move my Cakephp 2 project and I want to keep the same database. I have used a hash 'sha1' and the Cakephp security.salt to encrypt the users passwords:

```
public static function hash($password, $method = 'sha1', $salt = true) {
    return Security::hash($password, $method, $salt);
}
```

I added (a long time ago) in `myproject/app/config/core.php` this (with a different password):

```
    Configure::write('Security.salt', 'T4R393b0qyJioxfs2guVoUubWwvniR2G0Fgartge');
```

Now I don't know how to use this Security.salt code with another framework. So please:

- Does anybody know if I could use this encryption in an Angular 2/4 project (e.g.)?
- Any other solution?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess what bcrypt rocks. salt is contained in the hash.

Comment: According to the documentation: The salt is a random string used in security hashed mehods. I don't know how it modifies the hash. Thanks

Comment: Yes, its just a random string, you can use it it in any framework. For higher security the salt should be unique for each user.

Comment: Angular is a front-end technology, it doesn't care about what you do in your back-end. I'd suggest to have a look at the source of `Security::hash()`, it's just very basic stuff. **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.9.9/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L108**

Comment: What framework do you want to go?

Comment: In a new framework you must use the same hash algorithm - SHA-1.

Comment: Let's forget Angular, please. I know that I can use this random string (the Security.salt) in any framework, but I don't know how. I know how to use the hash _sha1_ , but what do I do with that string?

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Thanks to everybody.

I have to concatenate the salt and the password. After that I do the hash 'sha1'.

e.g.: `hash(Security.salt . $password)`

Found it in `myproject/cake/libs/security.php` as 'ndm' said:

```
function hash($string, $type = null, $salt = false) {
    $_this =& Security::getInstance();

    if ($salt) {
        if (is_string($salt)) {
            $string = $salt . $string;
        } else {
            $string = Configure::read('Security.salt') . $string;
        }
    }

    ...
```